# perl regex to match string length

Tags: regex, perl

I have a requirement where I will check the length of each line in a file using perl-regex and regex is supposed to match only if the length is 9 or 10 chars long.

Current regex: `/^(.{9,10})$/`

```
Sample input:
D   ABCD12
D   ABCD1
D   ABCD123
D   ABCD12
D   ABCD
D   ABCD1
```

`"D   ABCD123"` and `"D   ABCD"`, should not be matched remaining are to be matched.

Somehow my regex is not giving me desired results, where am i going wrong?

I am testing here:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Adding following details based on comments:
( I am using some shitty internal framework for these matching).
My result from test:
1) Input as above, regex as above
2) Selected m (multi-line) and g (global) options

```
Output:
$var = $input =~ /$regex/g
$var=1
$`=D   ABCD12 

$&=D   ABCD1 
$'=
D   ABCD123 
D   ABCD12 
D   ABCD 

-----------------------------------------
split($regex, $input)
[0]=D   ABCD12 

[1]=D   ABCD1 
[2]=
D   ABCD123 
D   ABCD12 

[3]=D   ABCD 
[4]=

[5]=D   ABCD1
D   ABCD1
```

Comment: Make sure you use the [`m` modifier](http://regex101.com/r/sZ9yA7).

Comment: How are you performing the match? It is quite important to know. We can always make assumptions, but in the long run it gets tedious to guess. Post working code including input, show what it outputs and what you expected it to output.

Comment: Are you reading the sample input row by row? Which results do you get? You need to give some more details, the regex itself does look OK.

Comment: Note that `/^(.{9,10})$/` can match `"123457890\n"` (11 chars). Use `\z` instead of `$` to fix that.

Comment: I think using a regex to calculate the length of a string is possibly one of the least efficient ways to do it... It's at least a fair distance from being the most efficient...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex is correct. (The outer parentheses are unnecessary, though).

In a regex tester, if you're using a multi-line string for testing, you need to use the `m` and `g` modifiers: http://regex101.com/r/tI3iA3

In your code, that means:

```
@var = $input =~ m/^.{9,10}$/mg;
```

Comment: I am using this regex in my "framework"
s/^(.{9,10})$/ TEMP $1 /gm.

But somehow the "TEMP" variable does not have correct information line wise, Though the example you have shown works perfect.

Comment: really liked your regex101.com link

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, I'm a stranger to Perl; I've edited the code sample according to what RegexBuddy is suggesting - is this better?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me - I think your regex is fine, so the problem must be the way you are reading in lines and testing them against the regex.

```
use strict;

open(FILE,"<test.txt");
while (my $line = <FILE>) {

    chomp($line);

    if ($line =~ /^(.{9,10})$/) {
        print "Matched\n";
    } else {
        print "Not Matched\n";
    }

}
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode; 

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp($line);

    print "\n$line\t";

    if ( length(Encode::decode_utf8($line)) ~~ [9..10] ) {
        print "true";
    } else {
        print "false";
    }
}

__DATA__
D   ABCD12
D   ABCD1
D   ABCD123
D   ABCD12
D   ABCD
D   ÄŒcd1
```

Comment: You should never ever use `_utf8_on`. If you do, you are doing something wrong. In this case, you want `$line = Encode::decode('utf8', $line);`, `$line = Encode::decode_utf8($line);`, `utf8::decode($line);`, etc.

Comment: `~~` is experimental and warn as such in 5.18+

Comment: This will be far slower than a regex solution.

Comment: @ikegami: I use 5.14 and I have no warnings.

Comment: 5.14 came before 5.18

Comment: Note that `use utf8;` would decode `DATA` too, being the same handle Perl uses to parse the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your input actually has trailing blanks.  This looks like mainframe stuff, and mainframes love to leave trailing blanks.  Try trimming trailing blanks, first, using `s/\s+$//` before matching.